# Avoid modifying REAL's config when upload DEV's config

Tags: configuration, web

I'm developing a website. I have two environments: DEV and REAL. Each of them have a config.php to store database configuration and something.

When I modify something in DEV's config.php and upload to REAL for production, I don't want to modify user and password in REAL's config.php.

For example:

```
DEV's config.php
user: abc
password: abc
// something below for development

REAL's config.php
user: xyz
password: xyz
// something below for production
```

**If I modify "something below" in DEV's config.php and upload to REAL, I don't want to modify user and password from "abc" to "xyz". Any solutions?**

Answer (score 2):

Include another file with the relevant parts that you don't upload.